# Recall global parameters: std::shared_future<std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter>>

Tags: ros2, rclcpp, parameter-server

I'm looking to retrive some global parameters (the name of my topics) from an yaml file that is shared by a global_parameter_server node. Now from another node I'm trying to recall these parameters.I'm doing it in  part, I can print them by RCLCPP_INFO just with the function  callbackGlobalParam, but I don't know how to get them as variables, as I have done in the // NEW PART in the code; in particular here I don't recive any error, but the terminal is just waiting for something... I can't block it with ctrl + c. I need to reach the variable associated to "LOG_TOPIC_PATH" . Many thanks if you can help me! :)

````
{
public:
    // Constructor for TcRunnerNode
    TcRunnerNode() : Node("tc_runner_node")
    {
        arto_parameters =
            std::make_shared<rclcpp::AsyncParametersClient>(this, "/global_parameter_server");
        arto_parameters->wait_for_service();

        auto parameters_future = arto_parameters->get_parameters(
            {"LOG_TOPIC_PATH"}, std::bind(&TcRunnerNode::callbackGlobalParam, this, std::placeholders::_1));

        // NEW PART
        std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter> parameters = parameters_future.get();
        if (!parameters.empty())
        {
            for (const auto &parameter : parameters)
            {
                if (parameter.get_name() == "LOG_TOPIC_PATH")
                {
                    // Found the parameter by name
                    RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Received parameter: %s", parameter.as_string().c_str());
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(get_logger(), "Failed to retrieve parameters.");
        }
        // END NEW PART

        // Create a publisher of "std_mgs/String" messages on the "log_topic" topic.
        log_topic_pub_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Int16>("LOG_TOPIC_PATH", 1000);

        // Change the current node state
        framework_fsm_msg_.data = static_cast<int>(FRAMEWORK_FSM::INITIALIZATION);

        // Set the connection status to true
        connection_status_msg_ = true;

        // Use a timer to schedule periodic message publishing.
        timer_ = create_wall_timer(
            std::chrono::seconds(1),
            std::bind(&TcRunnerNode::mainLoop, this));
    }
    void callbackGlobalParam(std::shared_future<std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter>> future)
    {
        auto result = future.get();
        auto log_topic_path = result.at(0);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "LOG_TOPIC_PATH: %s", log_topic_path.as_string().c_str());
    }```
````